# SSRS Column group division query

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I’m having a problem with division in my report where its not calculating correctly for the month/year column (CalHeading), which has its own column group.

My expression for both currently below is:
=Sum(Fields!PeriodSales.Value)/Sum(Fields!PeriodSales.Value, "Customer")

[image: Report Code]

[image: Groups]

As below 72.64% is displaying correctly for the period total column, but the 3.03% should be displaying 94.03%

[image: Report Result]

Edit - I had the wrong code in that was displaying 3.03%, but its still incorrect.

What it looks like its doing is for example putting Feb 2022 as 22.64% of the whole period total column (1,040,677.83 of 4,596,041,37)

[Temp Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMep2.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: On the face of it, it looks like what you are doing is correct but it will be related to the textbox's context. What I would do is add a temp column inside your Calheading group and set the value expression to be `=Sum(Fields!PeriodSales.Value, "Customer")`. I suspect the number you see there might not be the one you are expecting (4,596,041). Once this is done, maybe post some more results showing the new column. It might point us in the right direction.

Comment: I need to find a way to reference the static in the group for the total which is displaying £1,1,06,710.77

Comment: Since your column group is already grouped by customer, should the expression be =Sum(Fields!PeriodSales.Value)/Sum(Fields!PeriodSales.Value, "CalHeading2") That would be the group value of the Customer per period, instead of overall.

Comment: Unfortunately using =Sum(Fields!PeriodSales.Value)/Sum(Fields!PeriodSales.Value, "CalHeading2")  returned the 3.03% and =Sum(Fields!PeriodSales.Value)/Sum(Fields!PeriodSales.Value, "Customer") returned 22.64%

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it to work by referencing the text box; e.g.,

```
=Sum(Fields!PeriodSales.Value)/ReportItems!Textbox306.Value
```

Will this cause any issues going forward?

Comment: I don't think so other than, if memory serves me, that you cannot sum ReportItems!TextBox.Value across pages. I may be wrong but worth checking.